# How do I determine if a database is the principal in a mirroring setup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, mirroring

I have two database servers `Server1` and `Server2`, configured with mirroring.  A single database, `MirrorDB`, is mirrored. There is another database on `Server1` named `OtherDB` which is only present on `Server1` and is not mirrored. `OtherDB` has a stored procedure named `SP_Z` which refers to a table in `MirrorDB` to compute some value.

When `Server1` is the principal for `MirrorDB` the `SP_Z` stored procedure in `OtherDB` works perfectly, however when `MirrorDB` fails over to `Server2` the `SP_Z` in `OtherDB` fails as it can not open `MirrorDB`.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

At first I was expecting your error to be located at the point of retrieving `SP_Z` procedure. Sorry for being hasty.

[This link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/glennberry/2012/03/27/sql-server-database-mirroring-tips-and-tricks-part-3/) gives an explanation on how to query database mirroring status of your database. So, you do the following:

```
DECLARE @MirroringRole int;
SET @MirroringRole = (SELECT mirroring_role
    FROM sys.database_mirroring
    WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = N'DB_X');   -- your database name here
IF @MirroringRole = 2 -- Mirror
    -- connect to the failover partner server, using your database
ELSE IF @MirroringRole = 1 -- Principal
    -- connect to this server
END IF
```

Comment: Good solution .... just to add few cents ....To connect to the principal (when mirroring trips down), you need to configure Linked server and make sure that you set RPC and RPC out properties to "TRUE". then you can use 4 part convention to execute the SP e.g. exec [linkedserver].[dbname].[schema].[sp_name].

Answer (score 1):

Generally when connecting to mirrored databases, you wouldn't just connect directly to the principal instance, you would use a connection made by the native client or odbc driver as specified in the link below which would know about the failover partner and retry the connection on that if it couldn't access the principal:

[Connecting Clients to A Mirrored Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175484%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

As it seems you are connecting directly (via a linked server I presume???) you may need to incorporate some try catch logic into your procedure perhaps?

EDIT:

I did a bit more research on this and if you are using a linked server connection to your mirrored database, you can set up your linked server so that it supports database mirroring by following the instructions in the article below:

[SQL Server linked server that supports database mirroring failover](http://passionforsql.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/sql-server-linked-server-that-supports.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my SQL jobs. Hope it helps.

```
DECLARE @offline int

SET @offline = (
select state from sys.databases where name = [DATABASE_NAME]
)

If @offline = 0
     BEGIN
          -- Database is in principal mode
     END
Else If @offline = 1 
     BEGIN
          -- Database is in mirrored mode
     END
```

Comment: why would you use sys.databases when mirroring has its own DMV's that will give accurate information ?

Comment: What difference does it make if I query sys.databases or sys.database_mirroring?

Answer (score 0):

I have this script I generally use before I need to DETACH a database. it tests for mirror too.

```
USE MASTER
GO

--===========================================================
-- before detaching the database
-- see what files it has and where they are located

-- checks mirror and replication
-- database must not be part of mirror (neither as principal nor mirror) in order to be detached
--===========================================================
SELECT d.name 
      ,f.physical_name
      ,f.type_desc
      ,DB_in_Mirror=COALESCE(m.mirroring_role_desc,'Not Part in Mirror')  --database must not be part of mirror (neither as principal nor mirror) in order to be detached
      ,[Size (Gb)]=CAST(f.size/1024.00/1024.00 AS NUMERIC(18,2))
 FROM sys.databases d
      INNER JOIN SYS.master_files f 
                 ON d.database_id = f.database_id

      LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_mirroring m
                      ON d.database_id = m.database_id            
where 1 = 1
  AND d.state = 0 -- online 
  AND D.is_published = 0 -- not on replication
  AND d.is_subscribed = 0 -- not on replication
  AND d.is_merge_published = 0 -- not on replication
  AND d.is_distributor = 0 -- not on replication
  AND d.name like '%OrderArchive' -- the dbs that i need to detach have OrderArchive at the end of their names
```